# Built-in list of numeric types in Matlab

Tags: matlab, types

Does Matlab provide a list of numeric datatypes?

Some functions, like [zeros](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html#d123e1542635), take an optional `typename` argument, a string naming a numeric type (e.g., 'double' or 'uint8'), that determines the type of the returned array. I would like to add something similar to my own code, and a complete list of numeric types would help with argument validation, as in:

```
    ip = inputParer()
    ...
    ip.addParameter('DataType', 'double', @(x) ismember(x, numeric_types()));
```

It seems as though something similar must exist, but I haven't been able to find it.

- `isnumeric` checks an instance, rather than the typename itself.
- `superclasses` doesn't return anything for numeric types on 2018b.

Obviously, this is not hard to implement, but it'd be nice to use a built-in if it existed.

Comment: The documentation of `typecast` (not necessarily exhuastive, but probably so) says  `single`, `double`, `int8`, `int16`, `int32`, `int64`, `uint8`, `uint16`, `uint32`, `uint64`.

Comment: my two cents : https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/fundamental-matlab-classes.html

Comment: Thanks! The docs for R2018b's `isnumeric` also lists those ten types "and any subclasses of those types", which is what sent me down this particular rabbit hole (and made me think there should be some way to list them programmatically).

Comment: Note that the relatively newer "half" data type is not implemented as a simple numeric type like all of the others noted above.  Rather, "half" is implemented as a opaque classdef OOP object.  For some usages this doesn't make a difference (e.g., simple arithmetic expressions work as expected), but for other usages it does (e.g., typecast does not work). I would have preferred "half" to have been implemented as a simple numeric type and told The Mathworks the implications of their choice, but I doubt it will ever be changed. Maybe if they do bfloat16 in the future it will be done differently?

Comment: E.g., see this discussion: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/520582-why-is-the-new-half-data-type-an-opaque-class?s_tid=srchtitle